# How to put a comma between a pattern of characters?

Tags: r

I am using R to process a `data.frame`; one column has a certain mixture of letters and numbers, I want to put a comma between a pattern of characters:

Input:

```
 arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x311p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3
 arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x211p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat
 arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat
```

Desired output:

```
 arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3
 arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x2,11p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat
 arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat,13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat
```

Basically, I want to put a comma after the first `(xxx-xxx)x1` (here could be x1,x2,x3, then there could be a "mat", "pat" after x1).

Many thanks to MichaelChirico and Onyambu, I extracted more contents from that column,

Input 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x311p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x211p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat', 'arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~3 Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3)', 'nuc ish(D21S259/D21S341/D21S342x3).arr(21)x310q26.12(121812494-122486677)x1'

output 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x2,11p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat,13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat', 'arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~3, Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3)', 'nuc ish(D21S259/D21S341/D21S342x3).arr(21)x3,10q26.12(121812494-122486677)x1'

I am trying to us the following code, but works for all the situation,

x <- c( 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x311p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x211p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat', 'arr[hg19] Xp22.33p22.12(60701-21536551)x1~3 Xq21.31q28(90731177-155208244)x1 ish', 'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3)', 'nuc ish(D21S259/D21S341/D21S342x3).arr(21)x310q26.12(121812494-122486677)x1' ) sub(pattern = '([)]x[1|2|3|1~2|1~3]\s[mat|pat|dn]?))', replacement = '\1,', x=x)

Comment: Can you bold where you want to put the commas? Or please use backtick ```` to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub("(\\).*?)(\\d{2}[a-z])","\\1,\\2",x)
[1] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3"
[2] "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x2,11p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat"                             
[3] "arr 11p15.52097357-2432381)x1 mat,13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified as "sub("(\\).*?)(\\d+[a-z])","\\1,\\2",x)" because another row in this dataframe is "arr 11q14.3(90597564-90661199)x1 mat14q21.1(41517105-41696288)x1 pat".            Then I have another question related this: there are some row already have a comma, I don't want to add additional comma for those row, for examples: "arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x3,11p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3)"

Comment: Please edit your statement so that I may see what you mean. use backticks ```` to quote your data

Answer (score 0):

You said

> I want to put a comma after the first `(xxx-xxx)x1`

But your third case contradicts this. Until you clarify your rule for substitution, you can try, for your vector of strings `x`,

```
sub('([(][0-9]{7}-[0-9]{7}[)]x[0-9])', '\\1,', x)
```

[Explore what's going on here](https://regex101.com/r/RvySo5/1/).

You might also want to replace `[0-9]` with `\\d`, which is slightly more robust to locale:

```
sub('([(]\\d{7}-\\d{7}[)]x\\d)', '\\1,', x)
```

To accommodate the `mat` in the third attempt, you might try:

```
sub('([(]\\d{7}-\\d{7}[)]x\\d(\\smat)?)', '\\1,', x)
```

But this is highly custom-tailored to fit exactly your example.

Answer (score 0):

Can do the following

```
x <- c(
    'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x311p15.4(3424982-4083881)x3 pat.nuc ish11p15.5(RP11-558K10x3',
    'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x211p15.4(3224902-4383881)x1 pat',
    'arr 11p15.5(2097357-2432381)x1 mat13q15.4(3224902-3483881)x1 pat'
)
sub(pattern = "([(][0-9]+-[0-9]+[)]x[0-9])([^[:space:]].*)", replacement = "\\1,\\2", x = x)
```

Here is a brief explanation:

1) Regexp for matchin `(xxx-xxx)x1` is `[(][0-9]+-[0-9]+[)]x[0-9]`, here I used `[]` instead of escaping to match `(`. Rest can be read as numerics any number of times `[0-9]+` followed by `-` followed by numerics any number of times `[0-9]+` followed by `)`, `x` and a digit `[0-9]`.

2) Using capturing groups to split string and concat later, we split string on non whitespace character followed any number of characters `([^[:space:]].*)`, so that the pattern in 1 is in first group and the rest is in second. And concatenate 2 groups adding `,` like this `"\\1,\\2"`